# Adaptar un dataframe a un rango de fechas

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, pandas

mi duda:

Tengo un df (con `Fecha` como index y otra columna `Cantidad`) con registros cada 3er día desde el 2016-05-03 hasta el 2016-05-20, ejemplo:

> df.index[
>   2016-05-03,
>   2016-05-05,
>   2016-05-07...]

Con: `df = df.asfreq(freq='D')` me queda:

> [2016-05-03,
>   2016-05-04,
>   2016-05-05,
>   2016-05-06,
>   2016-05-07...]

Y con `df = df.fillna(0)` relleno con ceros en la columna `Cantidad` los nuevos registros.

**Pero lo que necesito es que me lo genere desde el 1ro de mayo hasta el último día de mayo.**  Ya teniéndolo así rellenar todos los demás días que se generen igual con 0's.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si he entendido bién lo que quieres una forma simple de hacer ambas cosas a la vez es usar `reindex`.

Para que pueda se reproducido por otros usuarios imaginemos que tenemos el siguiente csv:

> Fecha, Cantidad
>   2016-05-03,1
>   2016-05-05,2
>   2016-05-07,3
>   2016-05-09,4

Lo vamos a cargar en un `dataframe` para generar unos datos parecidos a los tuyos y después vamos a expandir el índice para que exista una columna por cada día del mes de forma que los dias nuevos que se agreguen tendrán una `Cantidad` de 0.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

csv = 'datos.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

#Las dos lineas siguientes son las que te interesan:
ix = pd.DatetimeIndex(name=df.index.name, start=date(2016,5,1), end=date(2016,5,31), freq='D')
df = df.reindex(ix, fill_value= 0)

print(df)
```

Salida:

> ```
>              Cantidad
> Fecha               
> 2016-05-01          0
> 2016-05-02          0
> 2016-05-03          1
> 2016-05-04          0
> 2016-05-05          2
> 2016-05-06          0
> 2016-05-07          3
> 2016-05-08          0
> 2016-05-09          4
> 2016-05-10          0
> ...
> 2016-05-30          0
> 2016-05-31          0
> ```

El rango de fechas del nuevo índice lo creamos con `pd.DatetimeIndex()` pasandole la fecha inicial mediante el parámetro `start` y la final con el parámetro `end`.

Comment: Aún no tengo reputación para dar la respuesta como útil. Gracias, reindex y DatetimeIndex son la solución a lo buscaba y y en efecto las dos líneas que indicaste que son de mi interés me resolvieron lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @JaimeHernandez ya has marcado la respuesta como útil, lo que no tienes es reputación para dar votos positivos/negativos (15) pero no te preocupes por eso. Me alegro de que te sirviera. Saludos.